# Understanding C linker error: multiple definition

Tags: c++, arduino, include

I have a project with multiple header files and `.cpp` files.
All of the header files have include guards.

There is a file called `Constants.h` where I define some constants. Some of these with defines, some as constant variables.

There are more header-`.cpp`-file pairs with code in them. One of these does contain a class, the others don't.

When I include my files into my main file (an arduino sketch), I get a lot of linker errors, claiming there are multiple definitions of some variables.

I read that this mainly occurs when you include `.c` or `.cpp` files, which I don't do. All the `.cpp` files only include their appropriate header files.

I did manage to find multiple solution proposals:

**1) `inline`:**

With functions, `inline` can be used to get rid of this problem. However, this is not possible with variables.

**2) anonymous `namespace`:**

This is one of the solutions I used. I put anonymous namespaces around all the problematic definitions I had. It did work, however I do not understand why this works. Could anyone help me understand it?

**3) moving definitions into `.cpp` files:**

This is another approach I used sometimes, but it wasn't always possible since I needed some of my definitions in other code, not belonging to this header file or its code (which I do admit is bad design).

Could anyone explain to me where exactly the problem lies and why these approaches work?

Comment: @NathanOliver - This question is about a subtle difference between C and C++. That dupe is rubbish.

Comment: @StoryTeller *There is a file called Constants.h where I define some constants. Some of these with defines, some as constant variables.* looks like a pretty clear cut dupe of the OP included variable definitions in multiple TU's.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Except in **C++** `const whatever bar = foo;` at namespace scope has internal linkage by default.

Comment: Is there any C code involved? Otherwise you might remove C language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some of these with defines, some as constant variables.

In C `const` does not imply the same thing as it does in C++. If you have this:

```
const int foo = 3;
```

In a header, then any C++ translation unit that includes the header will have a **static** variable named `foo` (the `const` at namespace scope implies internal linkage). Moreover, `foo` can even be considered a constant expression by many C++ constructs.

Such is not the case in C. There `foo` is an object at file scope with external linkage. So you will have multiple definitions from C translation units.

A quick fix would be to alter the definitions into something like this:

```
static const int foo = 3;
```

This is redundant in C++ but required in C.

Comment: That really cleared up a lot. Adding `static` to the problematic definitions did the trick. I'm just surprised that I never stumbled across this before...

Comment: @Lithimlin - Normally C headers will not have objects like that. And C++ headers will have other things that are way more likely to not be valid C.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Story Teller's excellent explanation, to define global variables, use the following:

```
// module.h
#include "glo.h"

// glo.h
#ifndef EXTERN
# define EXTERN extern
#endif
EXTERN int myvar;

// main.c
#define EXTERN
#include "glo.h"
```

In `main.c` all variables will be declared (i.e. space is allocated for them), in all other c files that include `glo.h`, all variables will be known.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare any object in header files, this should be moved to c\c++ files.

In header you may:

- declare types such as: `class`es, `struct`s, `typedef`s etc.
- put forward declarations of (not classes) functions
- put inline (or in classes) functions (+ body)
- you may add `extern` declaration.
- you may put your macros.

a `static` declaration may declare things multiple times, therefore it is not recommended.

Comment: Declarations are fine. Definitions are what causes trouble.

Comment: I contest your false assertion with `constexpr double epsilon = 1e-6;`